# Spring boot - change default Www-Authenticate errors

Tags: spring-boot, security

A security audit company tested our spring app and found that the Www-Authenticate errors are revealing 'too much info', I've been asked to change them all so that 'results are  helpful to the user without revealing unnecessary internal details.'.

I've been searching google / posts but have not found a way to do this, here are the problematic headers according to them:

**Expired JWT token:**

```
Www-Authenticate header will reveal error message: Bearer error="invalid_token",
error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Jwt expired at
2023-02-28T21:22:42Z"
```

**Manipulate expire date on token:**

```
Www-Authenticate header will reveal error message: Bearer error="invalid_token",
error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Signed JWT
rejected: Invalid signature"
```

**Change algorithm to None, new error message in Www-Authenticate header will be revealed**

```
Www-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="Unsupported algorithm of none"
```

To be honest I personally don't see these as problems but management want a totally clean report with no issues AT ALL, so I have three questions:

- How do I customize these spring messages?
- What should the messages here actually be? I can't think of anything that isn't going to be revealing except 'Invalid Token' or 'Expired Token';
- Are these actual security issues or is the company totally BSing us? I have high doubts in their ability at this point tbh.